# New Event and New Task link is not showing in Opportunity kanban view

Tags: lightning

Salesforce - Activity option not available on Kanban view in lightning. See screenshot below for reference. Where it says No Open Activities, user should be able to have a 'New Event' hyperlink.

When in opportunity kanban view, you should be able to hover over the orange warning triangle (warning is for no future activity scheduled for that opportunity), and create an event from the pop up window that appears.

Need assistance setting this up. Can anyone let me know where this setting is? There is no documentation online.

[image: Missing New Event Hyperlink]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly because you don't have the "New Task" and "New Event" Salesforce1 Actions on the Opportunity pagelayout associated with the Opportunity you are looking at in the Kanban view.

Add the "New Task" and "New Event" Salesforce1 Actions on the Opportunity pagelayout and then you should be able to see these in the Kanban view.[image: New and New Event in Kanban view]